# UPDATE month and year to current but leave day

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have situation in Oracle DB where I need to UPDATE every month some dates in table following this condition:

1) If date in table like '03.06.2017' UPDATE to '03.11.2017'

2) If date in table like '29.06.2016' UPDATE to '29.11.2017'

2) If date in table like '15.02.2016' UPDATE to '15.11.2017'

So basically always UPDATE part of date(month, year) to current month/year but always leave day as it is.

Edit:

It will be all months from 1-12 not only June. I need to do something like this... UPDATE table SET date = xx.(month from sysdate).(year from sysdate) WHERE... xx (day) leave as it is in DB.

Br.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you update `2017-09-30` and add 5 months? There are not 30 days in February.

Comment: It will always be dates < 05.mm.yyyy.

Comment: @MikeL - why does your sample data include '29.06.2019' then?

Comment: I will quota you for answer :-) "Because the state of your data tomorrow may will be different from its state today."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` to determine how many months you need to add and then use the `ADD_MONTHS` function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe001/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dates ( value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2017-06-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-06-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-31' FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```
UPDATE dates
SET value = ADD_MONTHS(
              value,
              CEIL( MONTHS_BETWEEN( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), value ) )
            );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM dates
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe001/1/0)**:

```
|                VALUE |
|----------------------|
| 2017-11-03T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-11-29T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-11-15T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-11-30T00:00:00Z | -- There are not 31 days in November
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want

```
update your_table
set this_date = add_months(this_date, 5)
where ...
```

This will add five months to the selected dates.

---

Your edited question says you want to update all the dates to the current month and year; you can automate it like this ...

```
update your_table
set this_date = add_months(this_date, 
                        months_between(trunc(sysdate,'mm'), trunc(this_date, 'mm')))
-- or whatever filter you require
where this_date between trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') and sysdate 
/
```

Using `month_between()` guarantees that you won't get invalid dates such as '2017-11-31'. You say in a comment that all the dates will be `< 05.mm.yyyy` but your sample data disagrees. Personally I'd go with a solution that doesn't run the risk of data integrity issues, because the state of your data tomorrow may will be different from its state today.

[Check out the LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:41:7869584532590:::41:SHAREKEY:FVIVUCX5UV5YN1RVCCAIV8N1F).

Comment: I must edit question :) It will be all months 1-12 not only June. I need to do something like this... UPDATE table SET date = xx.(month from sysdate).(year from sysdate) WHERE... xx leave as it is in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off with something like this to get my dates and then craft an update from it (substitute old_date with your date column and source_table with the table name):

```
select old_date, to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-') || to_char(old_date, 'DD') from source_table;
```

Comment: I think the most important requirement of date arithmetic is that it produces a valid date. But obviously your mileage varies.

Comment: That gives you a string, not a date; if you try to update the table column by converting that string to a date then it will fail for some cases (e.g. if the day of the month is 31, and the current month doesn't have 31 days). The OP has said in a comment that the day number will be < 5, but the question text contradicts that, and it isn't clear what should happen if the day can be higher. But even with that restriction, this still seems more complicated than using date arithmetic of some kind; converting to string and back feels awkward.

Comment: I agree, but he stated that having the same day is the most important part. That made it stand out as a text replacement question rather than a date manipulation question to me. OP can see the different approaches and use the one that works best for his use case.